How can number of cache hits for ODP.Net client side statement cache be measured?
Is there any way to know or measure ODP.Net client side statement cache hits?
We discovered that the ODP.Net client side statement cache grows to 200MB. This seems excessive and I'm going to turn it off using the following:
OracleConfiguration.StatementCacheSize = 0;
OracleConfiguration.MaxStatementCacheSize = 0;

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/ConfigurationMaxStatementCacheSize.html#GUID-62E036EC-56C4-4502-BB55-C06315CC2DF4
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/ConfigurationStatementCacheSize.html#GUID-4F5B67F7-E5AD-4487-B17D-5B66884BD946
However, it would be good to know if the cache is benefiting us.
We are using ODP.Net 23.4.0 but 3.21 has the same behavior.
I'm aware that there are performance counters (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/featConnecting.html#GUID-4FA1C8D3-195B-4D7A-9E9D-9FB74C7F5312) but none of them measure statement cache hits.
Any help would be appreciated.
